# Is it good/bad style to use aliases as abbreviation (in Python)?

Tags: python, coding-style

Is there any coding standard (in python) on the use of abbreviation variables as instances and/or class variables?

## Python example

The question is not necessarily tight to python and answers for other languages would be interesting as well, but I am especially interested in the pythonic or general way to do it.

```
import A
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = A.Very.Long.List.Of.Names.queue
```

`self.queue` is used just as an abbreviation for `A.Very.Long.List.Of.Names.queue` and used many times inside of Foo. This definetly makes the code shorter and easier to *read* but not necessarily easier to *understand* as the information about the structure is lost.

## Similar Questions

A similar question had been asked [Is it bad style to reassign long variables as a local abbreviation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260620/is-it-bad-style-to-reassign-long-variables-as-a-local-abbreviation) but I think this question has it's own right to be asked as the answer for local variables and an instance variables is likely to differ.

Comment: The Zen of Python tells us that `Flat is better than nested`. From that perspective, the style problem is not creating a temporary variable; it's having a sextuple-nested attribute in the first place. It's not always avoidable (e.g. if you're accessing a third party library whose interface you have no control over), but you can mitigate occurrences by prioritizing a shallow class hierarchy in your high level design.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
from A.Very.Long.List.Of.Names import queue
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue
```

This approach is better from perspective of performance, as it doesn't have to bear the overhead of **getattribute** and **getattr**

You can also declare the same in global section in your program like

```
import A
longVar = A.Very.Long.List.Of.Names.queue
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = longvar
```

This allows you to avoid from form of python import statement as well as making longVar available throughout your program.

Comment: Helpful, but doesn't really address the question he asked.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any standards that prohibit or discourage you from aliasing class names as far as I'm aware. Whether or not you should is mostly going to be opinion and heavily based on context.

In general if a class name is too long, I first look if I can refactor it. If I can't, I'll use an alias if it significantly improves readability. I'm not sure where your concern about "information about the structure" being lost stems from - any even slightly determined programmer will be able to identify an alias.

Sometimes it's easy to overthink these things.

Comment: What I mean with lost structure is that parts that form `A.Very.Long.Name` do contain information like `network_handler.messages.queue` or `gui.event_handler.queue` which are likely very different. At the point where the alias is defined they are hidden and any method using `self.queue` does not reveal this anymore and someone who wants to understand it has to go back to the definition of the alias. Without the alias any later use of `A.Very.Long.Name.queue` does reveal on which `queue` you are working on. I am afraid your answer might be true: it depends too much on the context.